# Twitter bootstrap - fields in the wrong order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I love Bootstrap but one annoyance that I can't seem to get my hands around is when building a form that starts with a simple text input box and to the right I'm putting some radio buttons (not the traditional type but Bootstrap refers to as "button groups"). Sadly the input box solemnly refuses to go to left, always jumping ship to the right of the stack. Why oh why? Any help is appreciated.

Here's a picture of what the form looks like:
[image: My form with the dyslexic controls]

And here is the code that led to this mutant disaster:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="appendedInput">Weight recorded:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input">
            <input class="input-small" id="weight" size="16" type="text" placeholder="weight" ready-for-history></input>
            <span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <button class="btn active">lbs</button>
                <button class="btn">kg</button>
                <button class="btn">stone</button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <p class="help-block">What weight were you?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is enough information for people to help me troubleshoot; let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esailija is correct. The buttons are floated left, so if you want to float the input box as well.  You can do this with some simple CSS:

```
#weight{float:left}
```

or

```
.input-small{float:left}
```

OR

You can use the Twitter Bootstrap `form-inline` class to ensure that all control-group elements are displayed inline (in the correct order).  Do this by adding the `form-inine` class to your `<form>` tag, or by wrapping your form fields in `<div class="form-inline">    ... </div>`

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for your sage advice. I have it working now. In case anyone cares I'll put my solution details below

Answer (score 0):

I added two CSS classes to solve this problem once Esailija and Eterps helped getting me focused on the right track. They are as follows:

```
.padded-left-form {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.clear-left-form {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}
```

I attached the .padded-left-form to the text input box to float it left of the radio buttons and then you need the .clear-left-form attached to the following "help-block" to bring it to the right spot vertically.

In the end here's what it looks like:

[image: updated with CSS]